# Hadoop, Jersey, and JBoss: application won't start

Tags: java, hadoop, jboss

I know barely anything about JBoss. Never touched it ever before yesterday, still don't really understand it. But, one of my company's clients is using it to deploy our application, and our latest update broke their configuration, so I'm trying to solve it.

Anyway, here's the version info:

Hadoop: 2.7.2

Jersey: 2.3

JBoss: 6.1

OS: Windows (I doubt this is OS-specific, that's just the environment I'm working on this in)

We recently added a Hadoop connector module to our application, and that seems to be what's causing the failure. I've been able to reproduce the issue, here is the stack trace:

```
13:32:39,857 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."eip.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."eip.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "eip.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/web/resources/UserProvider (Module "deployment.eip.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:232)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:161)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProvider
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProvider from [Module "deployment.eip.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        ... 20 more
```

So this UserProvider class, it seems to be setup to implement that Jersey interface. The thing is, that Jersey interface is a 1.x interface, and we have 2.x libraries in our application. We need to use the 2.x libraries for other components, there was actually a big migration to ditch 1.x for good a few months back.

So I'm just totally lost. I've tried everything I can think of to try and fix this. I've delved deep into the documentation on Weld, but whenever I try any of the configuration-based ways of disabled weld, I get an exception that it doesn't know how to parse XML elements that refer to weld.

JBoss is driving me nuts, but this client wants to use it, so we gotta find a way to support it.

So, here are the things I could really use help with:

1. Disabling the scanning process that is trying to load UserProvider to begin with. We're not using this class in any way shape or form in our application, we don't even want to.
2. Make JBoss work better with Jersey 2.3. Not entirely sure that'll be possible...
3. Hacky ugly ways to make this exception go away. Hopefully...
4. Anything else that I can do to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Hadoop 2.7 uses jersey 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Within this error I had to remove hadoop dependencies in version: 2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.4

and add jersey-server one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me bumping solr-solrj and solr-core from 6.2.1 to 6.5.1 fixed the issue, although I'm still seeing a warning about UserService. It was a strange error, because it appeared from one day to another, without making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this issue when using solr-core, had to remove the hadoop dependencies to fix this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>${version.solr}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Hadoop dependencies -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- Add more exclusions if needed -->
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```